# Using Language standard ISO c++ 98 with MinGW in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gcc, c++98

I want build my c++ project with ISO c++ 98 but when I build I have this in console :

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build
>   g++ -std=c++98 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\ProvaISO98.o" "..\src\ProvaISO98.cpp" 
>   In file included from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40:0,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
>                    from ..\src\ProvaISO98.cpp:9:
>   d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:164:11: error: '::vfwscanf' has not been declared
>      using ::vfwscanf;
>              ^~~~~~~~
>   d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:170:11: error: '::vswscanf' has not been declared
>      using ::vswscanf;
>              ^~~~~~~~
>   d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:174:11: error: '::vwscanf' has not been declared
>      using ::vwscanf;
>              ^~~~~~~
>   d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:191:11: error: '::wcstof' has not been declared
>      using ::wcstof;
>              ^~~~~~
>   In file included from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:39:0,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:44,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
>                    from d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
>                    from ..\src\ProvaISO98.cpp:9:
>   d:\programmi\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwctype:89:11: error: '::iswblank' has not been declared
>      using ::iswblank;

With ISO c++ 11 I haven't problem. Maybe I must change option -std=c++98 in -std=gnu++98 but I don't known how to do this.