# g++ std=c++98 doesn't compile in MinGW

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

Here's my code:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    cout << pow(4, 3);
    cin.get();      
}
```

So basically I try to compile with command `g++ main.cpp -std=c++98`

Here's what I get:

```
    C:\Users\NullPointerException\Desktop\cpp>g++ main.cpp -std=c++98
    In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:38,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                     from main.cpp:1:
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:166:11: error: '::vfwscanf' has not been declared
      166 |   using ::vfwscanf;
          |           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:172:11: error: '::vswscanf' has not been declared
      172 |   using ::vswscanf;
          |           ^~~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:176:11: error: '::vwscanf' has not been declared
      176 |   using ::vwscanf;
          |           ^~~~~~~
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwchar:193:11: error: '::wcstof' has not been declared
      193 |   using ::wcstof;
          |           ^~~~~~
    In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_facets.h:39,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h:37,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:44,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                     from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                     from main.cpp:1:
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\cwctype:89:11: error: '::iswblank' has not been declared
       89 |   using ::iswblank;
          |           ^~~~~~~~
```

Basically I wanted to test if c++ can deduce type for [pow](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/). But I get these errors. What's the problem and how do I fix it?

g++ version: 9.2.0

Comment: To sum up the discussion below, I see two options for you: 1. Switch to newer C++ (there is hardly any reason to code/learn in this old C++ version in 2021). 2. Switch to other compiler/IDE (I know either Visual Studio or clang with libc, e.g. maybe this would work https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-clang-aarch64-gcc-libs)

Answer (score 1):

I can compile this without problems using g++ 9.3 on ubuntu. Seems you have run into a bug specific to the mingw32 variant of g++.
You might try adding `include <cstdio>` and perhaps also `include <cstdarg>` before the other includes.
I cannot test this since I'm not using mingw32.

Comment: These missing functions are available since C++11: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfwscanf So I believe this is internal problem of MinGW. (Btw, proof that it compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/cbdEhPcbP)

Comment: @R2RT can I somehow show only warnings of "incompability of stantards" instead of non-compiling program? I searched the internet, but it seems like no.

Comment: `include <cstdio>` and `include <cstdarg>` didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @Learpcs Your problem is not that your code is not compatible with the c++98. This is - as R2RT wrote - most likely an internal problem of this specific compiler. You might consider reporting this as a bug.

Comment: @Learpcs These are hard errors of standard headers, so they cannot be disabled. I am afraid that this version of MinGW is not able to compile in c++98 mode.

Comment: Also, someone have faced this issue already back in 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391363/using-language-standard-iso-c-98-with-mingw-in-eclipse

Answer (score -3):

pow is a C function, not C++, so use the alternative C header for the math library.

Comment: I think using pow is fine, since cmath is included and we are using namespace std.

Comment: Yes but a "namespace" is not a  C entity, so when you try to use <cmath> with pow(), the compiler is looking through the C++ definitions for how to execute pow but will never find it. You need < math.h > as it contains all the prototypes for pow().

Comment: Sorry, but I beg to differ. ``std::pow()``  (which is the function being called in this example) is defined in <cmath>.

Comment: @AdaLovelace Since there is `using namespace std`, the compiler should look also for `pow` in `std` namespace, thus simply compile. (`::pow` call could fail). As it does in non-MinGW environment.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help. Same errors.